# Multiple UITableview Index bars

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am adding two UITableViews to my view in my code. I am properly setting the delegates and datasource to self. I have added all the delegate methods for returning the number of row, height for row, number of sections etc. And everything is working fine.  I have also added index bars to both tables. Now the problem is the index bar is not working for the 1st table, while it is working fine for the second table.

When I click on any character on 1st tables index bar, it responds for the 2nd table. I am not able to get the action for the 1st Table. I also noticed that if I don't add the second table to my view, then I am able to get the action for the 1st table.

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    accountsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,27, 320, 390)     style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [accountsTable setDelegate:self];
    [accountsTable setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:accountsTable];
    accountsTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [accountsTable release];

    keyConnectionsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 27, 320, 390) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [keyConnectionsTable setDelegate:self];
    [keyConnectionsTable setDataSource:self];
    [keyConnectionsTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [keyConnectionsTable setHidden:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:keyConnectionsTable];
}


- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index]; 
}
```

Comment: Just a small tweak.. try with assigning tags to the table view. I too have used more than one tableview at a time.

One more thing why you haven't release the second table?

Comment: You have added two table View at exactly the same place on your view.CGRectMake(0,27, 320, 390) Don't you think you should at the second table with some other frame Say - CGRectMake(0,475, 320, 390). I guess your second table overlaps the first one. Do you hide/unhide these table by some toggle switch ?

Comment: @RahulSharma : Yes u guessed it right. I have two buttons in my view, which i use to toggle between the tables. I hide/unhide the tables on the clicks of the buttons. My code is pretty huge, that is why i added only the code where i am facing problem. As i said earlier, everything else is working properly as it is supposed to work. I am only facing the index bar issue.

Comment: I just made a small demo using your code and it works fine. The Only point of mistake I see is when you make a selection to show/hide table views . Can you add some code for that ? Sounds weird but I made a mistake myself in choosing correct segment control index :-P

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate both table views. To do this you could simply use the "tag" property  and set it to different values, or you could have a `@property` in your view controller for each TableView.

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tv1;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tv2;
```

For your methods, you could do something like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView {
    if (tableView == self.tv1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (tableView == self.tv2) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

**Bottom Line**

You need to differentiate both TableViews or you're going to make a mess :)

Comment: I am differentiating both the tables exactly like u said. I have not added the table through nib file. Instead i am creating and allocing the table through code. I have added all the required methods and returning proper counts for them. everything is working fine except for the Index bars

Comment: Then why in the snippets that you pasted there is no differentiation? The indexes should be the same for each UITableView?